# Error while compiling mt6582 kernel source

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

```
LD      mediatek/kernel/drivers/conn_soc/drv_wlan/mt_wifi/wlan/built-in.o
LD      mediatek/kernel/drivers/conn_soc/drv_wlan/mt_wifi/built-in.o
LD      mediatek/kernel/drivers/conn_soc/drv_wlan/built-in.o
LD      mediatek/kernel/drivers/conn_soc/built-in.o
/home/saroj/android_kernel_huawei_h30t00-master/kernel-3.4/kernel/script/Makefile.build:443: recipe for target 'mediatek/kernel/drivers' failed

make[4]: *** [mediatek/kernel/drivers] Error 2

/home/saroj/android_kernel_huawei_h30t00-master/kernel-3.4/kernel
/Makefile:968: recipe for target 'mediatek/kernel' failed

make[3]: *** [mediatek/kernel] Error 2
```

Comment: `recipe for target ... failed` is normally because of **previous error**. But you don't show the message about the actual error.

Comment: Fix your question, i.e. add excerpt of the **actual error message**.

Comment: for Lenovo S930 this kernel compile well https://github.com/452/lenovo-android-phone-linux-kernel